# Seeking a Reference from an Instructor

Tags: funding, recommendation-letter, reference-request

I took a course with Professor X some semesters ago and enjoyed their teaching. I interacted with them outside of class but after that did not reach out to them. I am applying for a scholarship that requires a reference letter. I am hoping Professor X would be willing to write a letter speaking to my academic abilities that they observed in their course. I don't want to come across as self-centered and only reaching out when I need something, especially since I haven't initiated casual conversations before or initiated any interaction in general, and all interactions have always been work-related. Does anyone have any advice on how I can appropriately and respectfully ask them to consider writing a reference letter?

Comment: Can you arrange for an in-person visit?

Comment: Have you searched this question on this site?

Comment: This seems to answer your question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/178084/reconnecting-with-a-previous-professor-then-asking-right-away-for-a-reference-le